# I want my menu floated right until collapsed, then I want it centred

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've begun adding some Bootstrap to my website, but have come across a small problem. In my `navbar`, I have five menu items, that are floated right inside the `navbar` `div`. When I resize the browser, the menu items eventually collapse into a menu icon. Upon clicking this icon, the menu again appears, this time below the main `navbar`. I'm sure you are all familiar with what I am trying to explain, as this is the "preset" for Bootstrap.

My problem is that I want the menu items to be centred when the menu collapses, not floated right as it was before collapsing. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this though. Below is my HTML and CSS.

```css
.nav {
 list-style:none;
 float:right;
 margin:0;
}

.nav li {
 float:left;
 padding:16px 25px 13px 25px;
 font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size:17px;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

.nav li:hover {
 border-bottom:2px solid #1C1C1C;
}
   
.navbar-toggle {
 margin-top:13px;
}
   
.blog {
 margin-right:20px;
}
   
.collapse {
 height:56px;
}
   
.navbar-header {
 height:55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
       
    <div class="container">
       
        <div class="navbar-header">
            
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          
         </button>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         
          <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Gallery</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="blog">Blog</li></a>
      
         </ul>
        
        </div>
       
       </div>
       
   </div>
```

Comment: You could use media queries to target the specific screen size ( below @screen-sm-min ) and apply the centering rule only for those screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to control these behaviors. Just center the navbar-nav list item at under 767px.

You can also use some built in classes to place your navbar to the right. See `navbar-right` in the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

See working example Snippet.

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #1C1C1C;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1C1C1C;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">Gallery</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li class="blog"><a href="">Blog</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vanburen. I was able to figure out one way myself, but I thought I'd check back. This looks easier. Will give it a go!